I'm automatically converting raw product descriptions into meta description tags, but need to sanitise the inputs
I have a database of over 1000 items (and growing), each with a description, all stored as text.
Suppose I have the meta tag:
<meta name="description" content="<?=$description;?>">

Also, suppose it's working as intended, with one fatal flaw: I cannot trust any of the text descriptions to be "safe" in this context. They're supposed to be html formatted with html tags, but let's assume the worst.
I cannot find documentation anywhere that will even tell me what is and isn't safe. Exit characters, code injection, length limits, and so on. Just because it seems to run fine for now doesn't mean it's not causing issues I forgot to check for.
I expect the solution will be of the form below, but I have no idea what to use for the $pattern and $subject variables.
<meta name="description" content="<?=preg_replace($description,$pattern,$subject);?>">

I can translate the requirements into PHP myself, but I cannot work out what the requirements are.
If I'm lucky, maybe PHP already has a function that does all of this exactly.

I asked this question here, and to co-pilot at the same time. Co-pilot's solution: <meta name="description" content="<?=htmlspecialchars($description);?>"> Would that work?

Yes, that is sufficient. The main characters that need to be turned into entities are the quote mark and the angle brackets. The default options for that function are safe.

However if you are concerned that the string may be too long, you should also use mb_substr to cut it. For example, you can use say a 512 length, and any string that is shorter than that length will be affected. However you will need to know the encoding of the string; in general you can assume it is utf8, but it depends where it comes from.
